# Seachable source/version control application and code repository/library for very small projects

Tags: svn, version-control, tags, meta-tags, searchable

In my job we created one file or two Java files to pull data from a system and return an object to Jasper Reports.

I am looking for a source control system to use for this.  I have used subversion and I like it.  However, since they are very small, customized projects for a larger application, code reuse is very important.  I was hoping to find an application that would allow me to tag each file with searchable metadata.

I'd like to use tags in the sense that they are used here on stackoveflow, not the usual subversion sense of categorizing a group of files.

For instance, the person next to me could do a customization, but once he is done, if no one knows exactly what he did or for what client, the information is lost.  I am hoping he could tag his project with the proper keywords, so the next time a customization needs to be done that is similar to his, it would be easy to locate and reuse, rather than rewrite.

Does anyone know of an application that is capable of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Subversion properties on the top level directory: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html

However they're not as easy to search as you might like.  Another option is to use an issue/project management system that supports adding tags to issues and releases.  Asana and JIRA both offer something along these lines.